# Changing default player color globally on Tumblr

Tags: html, soundcloud

When posting a Soundcloud link on Tumblr, it automatically creates the embed code. But with this I don't have access to the parameters to add a different HEX color and customise my player within my blog.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this outside of the iframe and if possible do it globally so all my players will match.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use normal embed code from SoundCloud that allows you to do the customization instead of relying on Tumblr's integration.